# Call A Rest API that is secured with spring security

Tags: spring, api, rest, security

How do i call an api from an app secured by spring security.

I have a api provider completely secured with spring security.
Now i want to allow other clients/service to consume my rest from their apps. eg using jquery, php, etc. But my app is secured.

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can add the JSESSIONID in the rest-request as a cookie value. Then Spring-security will know that this is an authenticated user. I can only comment on using Rest client or template. Also, your question misses out too many details, which you should post, downvoting for that.

Comment: This is a broad question asked by a beginner on this subject. In my opinion it doesn't deserve a down vote. I don't think you have to be an expert to ask a question here.

Comment: That's right. The truth is that i have no idea what to use to authenticate clients. This is my first project dealing with rest. But if i pause the spring sec  from my app. clients are able to consume my api.

Comment: I tested it when with my simple consumer app using spring.

Answer (score 1):

A REST API is a set of URLs. You access these URLs secured by Spring in the same way you'd access any secured Web app.

That is, use a Web client, establish a session by using the authentication method configured, and send the HTTP method request you want.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice.

Comment: Do i need to provide my clients with my auth details or what can i use apart from using oauth.

Comment: If you're using oauth, they should be able to authenticate with their own credentials on the provider you're using.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Thanks very much. Then that just leaves me with how to configure aouth in my app. Thanks again.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.devx.com/webdev/create-your-own-rest-api-using-oauth-authentication.html